# Orthonormal regularizer to encourage diverse or non-redundant model parameters in neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization

I was recently reading the paper

- Nian, F., Chen, X., Yang, S., & Lv, G. (2019). Facial Attribute Recognition With Feature Decoupling and Graph Convolutional Networks. IEEE Access, 7, 85500-85512. (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8747501/)

and can't quite follow their method for encouraging orthonormal (or even orthogonal) features by constraining the model weights.

I inserted the relevant section below:

[image]

I am not quite sure how that approach is ensuring the the model parameters in $\theta_F$ are going to be orthogonal if that constraint is added to the loss function. I.e., suppose we have model parameters

$$
\theta_{f} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then

$$
\theta_{f}^\top \theta_{f} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a \cdot a + b \cdot b & a \cdot b + c \cdot d\\
b \cdot a + d \cdot c & c \cdot c + d \cdot d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

And the whole expression would be

$$
\lambda \bigg|\bigg|  
\begin{bmatrix}
a \cdot a + b \cdot b & a \cdot b + c \cdot d\\
b \cdot a + d \cdot c & c \cdot c + d \cdot d
\end{bmatrix}. - 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\bigg|\bigg|^{2}_{F}.$$

Now, I can see that if the covariance matrix instead of $\theta_{f}^\top  \theta_{f}$ was used how this would enforce an orthogonal constraint. But with the dot product, I am a bit lost.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not for nothing, but in the text, (2) writes $\theta_f^\top \theta_f$ but you write $\theta_F\theta_F^\top$. Even if we accept that $\theta_f = \theta_F=\theta$ in your question, you've reversed which one is transposed.

Comment: Thanks, made it more similar to the exact notation now. However, the issue/question should be the same.

Comment: Are you sure about the matrix-matrix product?

Comment: Are you asking whether orthogonality is **guaranteed?** Because it isn't. Rather, the regularization term incurs a penalty to the model whenever $\theta_f^\top \theta_f \neq I$. If the model can reduce total loss (the error loss plus regularization) by having a non-orthonormal $\theta_f^\top \theta_f$, then it will because the training procedure minimizes total loss. This is not much different from the typical $L^2$ penalty: $L^2$ penalty is minimized whenever $\theta_f$ is the zero matrix, but that model has too high a total loss; so instead, the model finds equilibrium between both losses.

Comment: No, I am not asking whether this is guaranteed. Rather, I am wondering how this would help at all. Nevermind though, I just remembered that $A^{\mathrm{T}} A=A A^{\mathrm{T}}=I$ for orthogonal unit (=orthonormal) vectors :P. I guess this question can be closed then. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: There's not really any reason to close the question (it's clear, it's on-topic, etc.) but if you feel that you know the answer then you can answer your own question by writing an answer in the Answer box below your post.

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the discussion in the comments, I remembered that for orthogonal basis vectors (i.e., orthonormal vectors), we have $A^{\mathrm{T}} A=A A^{\mathrm{T}}=I$. Hence,

$$\theta^{\top}_{f} \theta_{f} = I$$

if the vectors within the matrix are unit vectors. Hence, for a fully connected layer, this constraint will ensure that the vectors that compute the next (hidden or output) layer are orthogonal since

$$||\theta^{\top}_{f} \theta_{f} - I ||_{F}^{2} = 0$$ if the vectors in $\theta$ are orthonormal.